# How to duplicate entries and loop them without getting a Twig or deprecation error?

Tags: templating, error-message, loop, merge, deprecation

I'm trying to duplicate entries inside a macro, which will displays duplicated items inside a carousel.

It's not possible to merge Element Queries. Even if it's possible to merge IDs, merging an array of IDs will end up with non-duplicated entries.

This is how I duplicate entries:

```
{% set entries = entries | merge(entries) %}
```

After that, this is how I loop, and the resulting issue:

- `for entry in entries.all()`

  - → Twig error: Impossible to invoke a method ("all") on an array;
- `for entry in entries`

  - → deprecated warning: *Looping through element queries directly has been deprecated. Use the all() function to fetch the query results before looping over them*;
- `for entry in entries.all() ?? entries` or `entry in entries ?? entries.all()`

  - → same warning as previous point;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of duplicating the entries, you could run your `entries` loop twice (or as many times as you want) maybe?

```
{% for i in 0..1 %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {{ entry.title }}   <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```